# Get firebase data order by descending date key

Tags: java, android, firebase

Good Afternoon. I'm having a problem whenever I'm displaying the data from `firebase` . It was shown in a `recyclerview` but the arrangement in the `recyclerview` must the latest date first.

The date 2/1/2018 must be first on the list.  Here is the codes on how I select the data.

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("complaints");


        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try{


                    list = new ArrayList<Blog>();
                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        Blog value = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Blog.class);
                        Boolean Posted = value.getPosted();
                        String complaint_type = value.getComplaintType();

                        if (Posted== true && complaint_type.equals("Civic Complaint")) {
                            int ComplaintNo = value.getComplaintNo();
                            String Description = value.getDescription();
                            String Date = value.getDate();
                            String MediaURL = value.getMediaURL();
                            String Time = value.getTime();
                            String Address = value.getAddress();
                            int count_satisfiedd = value.getCount_Satisfied();
                            int count_dissatisfied = value.getCount_Dissatisfied();
                            boolean posted = value.getPosted();


                            Blog fire = new Blog();
                            fire.setComplaintNo(ComplaintNo);
                            fire.setDescription(Description);
                            fire.setDate(Date);
                            fire.setMediaURL(MediaURL);
                            fire.setTime(Time);
                            fire.setAddress(Address);
                            fire.setPosted(posted);
                            fire.setCount_Satisfied(count_satisfiedd);
                            fire.setCount_Dissatisfied(count_dissatisfied);
                            list.add(fire);
                        }

                    }

                    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list,getActivity());
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyce = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),1);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyce);
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);


                }catch (Exception e){


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

And here is the database:

```
"complaints" : [ null, {
    "Address" : "Earth Street ",
    "CivicCategory" : "",",
    "ComplaintNo" : 1,
    "ComplaintType" : "",
    "Date" : "02 / 01 /2018",
    "Description" : ".",
    "MediaType" : "Image",
    "NearIn" : "Palengke ",
    "Posted" : true,
    "Time" : "11:42 AM"
  }, {
    "Address" : "Mars Street ",
    "CivicCategory" : " ",
    "ComplainantID" : "voter1",
    "ComplaintNo" : 2,
    "ComplaintType" : "",
    "Count_Resolved" : 0,
    "Count_Solved" : 0,
    "Date" : "01 / 03 /2018",
    "Description" : "
    "Posted" : true,
    "Time" : "11:43 AM"
  } ],
```

How could I get the expected result?

Thank you for helping

Comment: Before inflating list in Recyclerview you can sort list by date.

Comment: Thank you. But i have tried that. I put myRef.orderBy("date"), but it also diplays not the latest date

Comment: I tried to upload an image but I can't

Comment: I think your question is regarding Arraylist items order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reverse the list before you pass it to the adapter

```
Collections.reverse(yourList);  //   <---- reverse the list

RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list,getActivity());
RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyce = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),1);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyce);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
```

Comment: I declared a List as List<Blog> list;

Comment: There is no Lists.reverse(list);

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can follow one of below two ways,

One way-

After inserting values in arraylist, sort it by "date" key

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<ClassObject>() {
@Override
    public int compare(ClassObject o1, ClassObject o2) {
        // here you need to convert string to date format
        return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
    }
});
```

Another way-

While inserting data in firebase database use [timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) format or a string that is lexicographically sortable because firebase database maintain lexicographically ordering. (Current "Date" value format is not lexicographically sortable.

Then your query would be like,

```
ref.orderByChild("Date")
```

I have attached an image where I have used "timestamp" key. I am getting sorted result by using this.

[image: Separating insertion using timestamp]

**You might need to do some logical things according to your structure.**